# Error handling using typescript decorators does not work as expected

Tags: javascript, typescript, error-handling, decorator

I looked into error handling using decorators in typescript and found a behaviour I did not expect

```js
function handleError(): any {
    return function (_target: any, propertyKey: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) {
        const original = descriptor.value;
        if (typeof original !== 'function') return;

        try {
            const result = original.apply(this, arguments);
            return result;
        } catch (e) {
            console.error(`An error occurred!\nFunction: ${propertyKey}\nError: ${e}`);
        }
    };
}

class test {
    @handleError()
    mightThrow() {
        throw 'Oh no, an error occurred!';
    }
}

new test().mightThrow();
```

When running this code I get the following console output:

```js
An error occurred!
Function: mightThrow
Error: Oh no, an error occurred!

/home/venny/Projects/lol/index.js:28
        throw 'Oh no, an error occurred!';
        ^
Oh no, an error occurred!
(Use `node --trace-uncaught ...` to show where the exception was thrown)
```

Why do I still get the standard nodejs uncaught exception console output here, even though I caught the error in the decorator function?

Comment: Well, you are logging the entire error

Comment: It's logged to console right there: `Error: ${e}`